# CSS 3 - shadows and rounded corners

Tags: css

I faced a very interesting fact, and hope you have an answer for that.

I have this code:

```
width:940px; margin:0 auto; padding:13px 29px 39px 31px; background:#fff;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
       -moz-border-radius:10px;
            border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 2px 1px #e3e6e9;
       -moz-box-shadow:0 0 2px 1px #e3e6e9;
            box-shadow:0 0 2px 1px #e3e6e9;
```

I saw it on Joomla 1.6 template - and it works cool on IE8, but when I pasted the same code to my template, it doesn't work on IE8, maybe there are some tricks to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Of course it doesn't work in IE8, IE8 doesn't support anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet explorer doesn't support `border-radius` and `box-shadow`. There are some projects that try to bring css3 to ie like [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/) or [ie-css3](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/). Of course for shadows you can use filters. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: have a look at css3please.com as well

Comment: Internet Explorer 9 supports border-radius even if not completely

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, that code doesn't work on IE8. Most likely there is a IE8 only stylesheet that uses images to get the same effect.

Personally I just let IE8 and below be a little blocky if I can get away with it. The % of users on those browsers is diminishing fast and I don't mind helping that along. And if your rounded corners are subtle then it's not something many users would even notice. Same goes for box shadow.